# Get number of nodes in a dask array task-graph

Tags: python, dask

How can one get information about the actual size of a dask arrays **task-graph**?

With *size* i mean the total number of nodes across all layers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a collection (like a array), the high-level graph can be found from the collections `.dask` attribute. The size, in tasks, of this graph is simply it's length

```
len(arr.dask)
```

If you want more information on its low-level representation, you can also cast to a dictionary

```
dict(arr.dask)
```

Note that high-level graph has a HTML visualisation that will automatically show up in a jupyter notebook, or you can call the `.visualize()` method to get a graph view (in the notebook or a file) to get more information on the layers and their contents.